# Xcode not bundling all launch images in iPA

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, xcode10, iphone-xs-max

In my application, I have total 5 launch images. During debug build I when I run app on iPhone X simulator then everything looks fine. But, when I archive it and upload iPA then launch images of iPhone X and iPhone Xs Max not bundling in iPA. So when I launch application then on iPhone X and iPhone Xs max it showing black bar at top and bottom.

Is any one faced same issue then please give me some insight.

Xcode Version : XCode 10.1

Comment: It was happening due to iPhoneX and Xs Max launch images encoded as JPEG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was happening due to iPhoneX and Xs Max launch images encoded as JPEG. So, make sure that encoding is PNG.